How to save generator object to png, jpg or other image files
I'm using timeseries-generator from GitHub to get synthetic line graphs.
That works good.
But now I want to save the plots into a file as separate png images.
This is my code so far:
i=range(0,4) #first number inclusive, second exclusive

for element in i:
    outpath = "PATH"
    c=random.random()
    o=random.random()
    s=random.random()
    lt = LinearTrend(coef=c, offset=o, col_name="plot no. {0}".format(element))
    g = Generator(factors={lt}, features=None, date_range=pd.date_range(start="01-01-2020", end="12-31-2020"))
    wn = WhiteNoise(stdev_factor=s)
    g.update_factor(wn)
    g.generate()
    g.plot()
    g.savefig(path.join(outpath,"graph_{0}.png".format(element)))

The last line get me following error:
AttributeError: 'Generator' object has no attribute 'savefig'
The type of object g is:
print(type(g))

<class 'timeseries_generator.generator.Generator'>
I tried following suggestion from an other post:
Save image from generator object:
with open("output_file.png", "wb") as fp:
    for chunk in thumb_local:
        fp.write(chunk)

But that doesn't work for me.
Maybe I'm using it wrong, with:
with open("graph_{0}.png".format(element), "wb") as fp:
        fp.write(g)

I get following error:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Generator'
Is there a way to change the generator object into something else to save the images or is there a way to save the generator objects as png?
Or can I use the suggestion above, but do it wrong?
Thank you for your help in advance!

g.plot() simply calls the plot() method of the underlying Pandas dataframe. You should get the dataframe and export it on your own:
fig = g.ts.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20, 16)).get_figure()
fig.savefig(path.join(outpath,"graph_{0}.png".format(element)))


Thank you @s0mbre, but I don't understand, why I now get a totally different plot.
I run g.plot() and get an kurvy line chart. Afterwarts there is your suggestet code and I get a chart with totally different aes and 2 lines. I don't understand why, because the data of g - I assume - is given to the new plot with g.ts.plot....
Other way round, how do include I my  data? Is there a documentation for ts.plot()? I only found ts_plot() here: (https://climaf.readthedocs.io/en/master/_downloads/d4e6d7b3a4855f67418bb8808cf936e6/Getting-started-with-ts_plot.html) but is something different. Thx

Ok, I get another hint, ich have to do: g._ts.plot() in my code and save it in a variable. Afterwards I have to do: fig.figure.savefig(FORMAT) and now it works. Thanks for your help!
